# How to re-height border for windows resize in XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, height, border

I have a more StackPanels in my XAML. Every StackPanel has a border inside.
When I modify the Main Window the width follows the resizing. But the height follows only in one the bigger direction. If I make the Window smaller the height of the borders doesn't follows. So the effect is the Botton border line isn't visible. How can I do this ?

```
<Window x:Class="MyStackPanel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MyCombobox" Height="356" Width="475">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="STP" 
                Margin="10">
            <Border x:Name="STPB"
                BorderBrush="#FFE80707"
                BorderThickness="5"
                CornerRadius="10"
                Height="{Binding ElementName=STP,Path=ActualHeight}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

![border normaly Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVwzu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Grid instead of a StackPanel then the border will stretch to the

Grids height and width on resizing

```
<Grid x:Name="STP" 
    Margin="10">
    <Border x:Name="STPB"
        BorderBrush="#FFE80707"
        BorderThickness="5"
        CornerRadius="10" />
    </Grid>
```

Window after your changes, Looks like the same after reize (make smaller) without your changes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SplMn.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try this and the result is, the border botton is permanent outside the window. With StackPanel the streching works fine in the bigger direction. Only if the window will be smaller (height) the border botton isn't visible.

Comment: outside the window? I don't understand. Could you post a screenshot?